# Enabling css class autocompletion in STS

Tags: css, eclipse, autocomplete, spring-tool-suite

Is there any way to allow auto-completion of the css classes in STS ( Spring Tool Suite / Eclipse ) I am using bootstrap and i would like to have the possibility to autocomplete the css classes i.e. when i type

```
<div  class="
```

to be able to get some css classes that bootstrap offers. Can this be done in eclipse / Spring Tool Suite? Currently I get the response  "No default Proposals"